# Measure how far you dragged with onTouchEvent in Android?

Tags: java, android, touch-event

Is it possible to measure how far someone has dragged their finger on the display using onTouchEvent? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You could just get the position of the event using `MotionEvent.getX()` and save the pos as two different variables; a `previous_pos` and `current_pos`, then calculate the difference. Check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getX(int)). When the first MotionEvent occurs, set the initial position to previous_pos, then the next would be current_pos. Set previous_pos as current_pos after every MotionEvent completes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` to store start and end point that finger touched and calculate the distance that  dragged.

For example:

```
Point p1;
Point p2;

View view = new View(this);

view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            p1 = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
         else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            p2 = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

         return false;
      }
});
```

and the distance is equal to `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x-p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y-p2.y, 2))`. And also, if you want to calculate the distance that dragged in any time, you can store the second position `if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)`.